# Ordering, where column contains same value

Tags: mysql, sql

Given table

```
 id | name
 ------------
 1  | mercedes
 2  | mercedes
 3  | mercedes
 4  | mercedes
 5  | mercedes
 6  | mercedes
 7  | mercedes
```

There are chance, that these 2 querys return same row?

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name LIMIT 0,3`

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name LIMIT 3,3`

That is, if each value for `name` column is same, just ordering with `name` column (with LIMIT clause) is reliable ?

Comment: i think so. because there are fallbacks in case that the sorting cant makes a decision which comes first, so it falls to the primary col sorting, or the raw bytes in the file. in the other hand its a bad coding. you should relay on your own query no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, chances are that different result are returned. But you can add another column to sort by

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY name, id 
LIMIT 0,3
```